# Exporting CiviCampaign Walk Lists without Reserving Respondents

Tags: civireport, civicampaign

I'm using CiviCRM for political campaigns and the process of reserving respondents is a major pain point for my clients. Most of the time you never know who or how many people will show up to knock doors, making it so you need to release and then re-reserve contacts in order to properly record who surveyed them.

It would be much easier if you could simply delete the requirement in the report to only look for reserve contacts and just export whatever list comes up on your filter. I've looked at the report template in code, but I can't decipher where exactly I would need to make changes to remove that requirement.

Has anyone ever attempted this before or have any suggestions on how to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping to overcome this by November. I will be offering a mobile app by subscription that automates much of this, but on the CiviCRM side there will be a couple of available extensions which provide the underlying functions.

My thought is to use geocoding and populate a list of volunteers creating a walklist smart group with each volunteer and their constituents. There would likely be a couple of custom fields added to contacts to record these activities.

However, without waiting for those extensions, adding a custom field plus smart groups, you could work out a solution on your own.